# how to use two "model" in the view ^^

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two model in the controller ^^
may I know how to use it in the view?

```
public class SearchVM
{
    public IEnumerable<StaffInfo> StaffInfo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TRecord> TRecord { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Search(int? id)
{
    var model = new SearchVM
    {
        TRecord = (from t in db.TRecordDBSet.Include("StaffInfo")
                          where t.StaffId == id
                          orderby t.StaffId, t.Tid
                          select t),

        StaffInfo = (from t in db.StaffInfoDBSet
                     where t.StaffId == id
                     select t)

        .ToList()
    };

     return View(model);
 }
```

when I use it in the view mode
the error occurs

view

```
@model IEnumerable<TrainingHourSystem.Models.TRecord>
```

the error msg :"傳入此字典的模型項目為型別 'THSystem.Controllers.TRecordsController+SearchVM'，但是此字典需要型別 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[THSystem.Models.TRecord]' 的模型項目。

Comment: Could you translate the error message in english?

Comment: Your model is `SearchVM` so the view needs to be `@model SearchVM`